# IIS serve https GET, but fails POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis

I'm setting up IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019. After I installed Let's Encrypt cert via *win acme* some url fails.

I've setup `ApploccationPoolIdentity` method for my web site. Here is my setup

[image]
[image]
[image]

So far I have most of paths are working. Fails:

- account/login and account/logoff
- some fonts (.woff2, woff, .ttf) see image below

All above fails with 403 Status code. But they working fine if

- open `localhost` on my VPS
- unbind hhtps (:443, ssl) and reach them using http

[image]

**UPD**

I found that ALL POST request fails (all forms), while all GET succeeded. Not Sure why fonts fails though.

**UPD 2**

POST methods work on postman and IE, but fails from Google Chrome.
Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**UPD 3**

2021-04-05 05:44:18 10.129.0.3 POST /profile/edit - 443 user@e.mail xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/89.0.4389.114+Safari/537.36 https://mymydomain.ru/profile/edit 403 0 0 93

**UPD 4**

Mime Types and Bindings are also attached
[image]
[image]

**UPD 5**

I found that everything works fine if I do request to subdomain, i.e. beta.mydomain.ru rather than mydomain.ru including http:// and https://.
FYI i've issued and tested with two certificates

1. *.mydomain.ru, mydomain.ru
2. mydomain.ru (without wildcard)

Comment: Need more information to solve the problem, you can read the web server logs, by default, these are stored in %SYSTEMDIR%\LogFiles\.

Comment: @samwu added log for failed POST request

Comment: @Adel-Nazirov, Have you checked IIS supported MIME file extensions for fonts? Could you show a screen of your website port bindings? Thanks.

Comment: @yW0K5o bindings attached

Comment: @Adel-Nazirov Could you assign IP addresses for http and https protocols?

Comment: @yW0K5o unfortunately I reverted website movement and put it back to azure for now. I can't bind main domain to this unstable vps because it will affect real users. I'm going to do a demo with different domain for now and try technic. And then do another try during the weekend when I have less amount of online users. Keep you posted. Thanks for your attention

Comment: @yW0K5o For my intermediate experiments I return main domain on stable server, and created subdomain to this new and I found that I don't have the issue described above if I call my server from subdomain i.e. beta.mydomain.ru works fine, but mydomain.ru didn't work.

Comment: Adel, You are welcome! I had something simmilar with `Let's Encrypt cert` in shared hosting. I played with http an https protocols and it was fixed. I made sure that all POST actions have https protocol calls.

Answer (score 1):

After spending lots of hours I gave up fighting this issue. Set up a new environment with a new certificate and everything is working fine.

Very likely could make a mistake when issued cert first time.